# How to retrive multiple values to jsp page from arraylist

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm setting array list of values like

```
              <%  while (rss.next()) {
                arrlist.add(rss.getString("Trx_No"));
                arrlist.add(rss.getString("Trx_Date"));
                arrlist.add(rss.getString("Trx_amount"));
                arrlist.add(rss.getString("Trx_Admin")); } %>
```

I have 20 values in this

and i want to set these in the Jsp page in the fields .

I did like  `<%=Trx_No%>`, `<%=Trx_Date%>` `<%=Trx_amount%>` `<%=Trx_Admin%>`

Problem is when i did like this im getting the values of tha last 4 in the arraylist. I want all the values intlo table

Answer (score 2):

Better way would be create a class that represent this Table for example

```
class TrxHelper{
 private Integer no;
 private Date date;
 private Double amount;
 private Long admin;
 //accessors, and other required stuff
}
```

from servlet fetch the data from DB and create a `List<TrxHelper>` and set it to request attribute and pass it to JSP,

On jsp using `<c:forEach>` and `<c:out>` render those in a tabular form

---

**See**

- [Hello World #2 (preprocess a request)](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)